# changing class variable permanent c#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, variables, methods

I need to change a class variable in a method that's inside the class,
how can I do it?

```
class MainGame
{
    public string Connected_IP = " ";
    public short Is_Connected = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new MainConsole());
        MainConsole m = new MainConsole();
    }
    public ref string checkCommands(string command)
    {
        IP_DataBase ips = new IP_DataBase();
        /*checking for ips in the list*/
        string[] dump;
        if (command.Contains("connect"))
        {
            dump = command.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < ips.IPS.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dump[1] == ips.IPS[i])
                {
                    Connected_IP = dump[1];
                    Is_Connected = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Connected_IP = "Invalid IP";
                    Is_Connected = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (command.Contains("quit")) /*disconnect command*/
        {
            Connected_IP = "Not Connected";
            Is_Connected = 0;
        }
        return ref Connected_IP;
    }
}
```

I expect that Connected_IP would change. but instead, the variable has changed just in the method, I tried using the     ref     command but still no change, what can I do?

```
public partial class MainConsole : Form
    {
        MainGame m = new MainGame();
        MainGame j = new MainGame();
        private void ConsoleInput2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                Text_IP_Connected.Text = m.checkCommands(ConsoleInput2.Text);
                if (m.Is_Connected == 1) vic_sft.Enabled = true;
                else vic_sft.Enabled = false;           
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where and how does`checkCommands()` get called?

Comment: Can you show a call of the checkCommands() method?

Comment: You're creating a separate instance of `MainConsole`, than what was passed to `Application.Run()`; this is also suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, I'm creating and storing an instance of MainGame, in the MainGame class itself.  Because this is done from static Main(), the declaration must be also be static.  Note that if this declaration was made `public`, then it could be accessed from anywhere using the syntax `MainGame.mg` (this is not the recommended approach, however).

Next, we pass that instance of MainGame to the MainConsole form, via it's **Constructor** in the `Application.Run()` line.  Note the additional constructor in MainConsole posted below.  The "ref" on the return type in `checkCommands()` has been removed, as the value could be changed using the passed and stored reference to MainGame, in MainConsole itself.

MainGame class:

```
public class MainGame
{

    public string Connected_IP = " ";
    public short Is_Connected = 0;

    static MainGame mg = null; // instantiated in Main()

    static void Main()
    {
        mg = new MainGame(); // this instance will be worked with throughout the program
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainConsole(mg)); // pass our reference of MainGame to MainConsole
    }

    public string checkCommands(string command) // no "ref" on the return type
    {
        IP_DataBase ips = new IP_DataBase();
        /*checking for ips in the list*/
        string[] dump;
        if (command.Contains("connect"))
        {
            dump = command.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < ips.IPS.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dump[1] == ips.IPS[i])
                {
                    Connected_IP = dump[1];
                    Is_Connected = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Connected_IP = "Invalid IP";
                    Is_Connected = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (command.Contains("quit")) /*disconnect command*/
        {
            Connected_IP = "Not Connected";
            Is_Connected = 0;
        }
        return Connected_IP;
    }

}
```

Here, in the MainConsole form, we have added an additional Constructor that receives an instance of MainGame.  There is a field called `m`, of type MainGame, but note that **nowhere** in this form are we actually creating an instance of MainGame with "new"; we are only using the instance that was passed in.  The reference to MainGame is stored in `m` from the Constructor so that it can be used at other points in the code:

```
public partial class MainConsole : Form
{

    // Note that we are NOT creating an instance of MainGame anywhere in this Form!

    private MainGame m = null; // initially null; will be set in Constructor

    public MainConsole()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainConsole(MainGame main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.m = main; // store the reference passed in for later use
    }

    private void ConsoleInput2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return && ConsoleInput2.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            // Use the instance of MainGame, "m", that was passed in:
            Text_IP_Connected.Text = m.checkCommands(ConsoleInput2.Text);
            vic_sft.Enabled = (m.Is_Connected == 1);
        }
    }

}
```